# JFrog on dedicated disk

Tags: amazon-ec2, artifactory, amazon-ebs

Is it possible to install JFrog on a separate disk? For example in an AWS EBS

I find their documentation a bit confusing, so i checked don't have a walk-through for this.
I'm looking at this documentation: [Installing on Linux Solaris or Mac OS](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-RPMorDebianInstallation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is.

You can install the ZIP installation and unzip it in the EFS.
Alternatively, install using Debian/RPM and mount the EFS to `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` in advance.

Alternative approach can be to only [configure the Filestore](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+the+Filestore) to use the EFS.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @Ariel Kabov